# Unable to play audio on device (iOS)

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, avfoundation, avaudioplayer

I am using the following code to play a audio in iOS using `**AVAudioPlayer**` class.

```
NSString *audioPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myAudio" ofType:@"mp3"];
NSURL *audioURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:audioPath];
NSError *error;
AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:audioURL error:&error];
audioPlayer.delegate = self;
[audioPlayer prepareToPlay];
[audioPlayer play];
```

This is working fine in simulator. But, i am not getting the sound output when i run it on the device. The delegate methods of`AVAudioPlayerDelegate` are also being called but there is no volume output. Where am i going wrong here.... Another important aspect i'v noticed here is that, i am getting a large message in my GDB while playing the audio file on simulator. But the same thing is not happening on device... Please refer the screenshot below for GDB messages while running on the simulator.

[image]

Comment: This happened to me once when I accidentally left the copy box checked when importing AVFoundation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was so so stupid.... My volume button was turned off. That was the reason.

Really sorry for wasting your time guys... My sincere apologies.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your device is on loudspeaker mode or not..

to listen  the sound through Loundspeaker use this -

```
// set audio to loudSpeaker mode for iphone
UInt32 audioRouteOverride = kAudioSessionOverrideAudioRoute_Speaker;
AudioSessionSetProperty (kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideAudioRoute,sizeof (audioRouteOverride),&audioRouteOverride);
```

or you can increase the volume of your audio file using this -

```
Player.volume = 10.0;
```

Comment: how to check if my device is in loud speaker mode?

Comment: Just set the above setting to play sound through Loud Speakers. If your sound play after this setting it means, sound was coming through microphones before..May be this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the .caf or .wav file? might possible that .mp3 is not working on iPhone. Also check the duration of your file not greater than 30 sec.